# Scanner input error

Tags: java

For an assignment, I have to write this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        //Display welcome message
        System.out.println("Welcome to the String Function Event!");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String result1;
        System.out.print("Please input the first word:");
        result1=userInput.next();

        String result2;
        System.out.print("Please input the second word:");
        result2=userInput.next();

        System.out.println("The words you chose are " +result1+ " and " +result2+ ".");
    }
}
```

When I try compiling it, it gives me 3 errors in the command prompt that say "cannot resolve symbol, symbol: class Scanner, location: class Words, Scanner userInput=new Scanner(System.in)". I'm not sure where the error is. 
Should I be using BufferedReader for the input instead?

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using? Scanner was introduced in the 1.5 (which is quite old at this point)

Comment: program looks fine to me

Comment: @SJuan76 OH! I just checked mine. It's 1.4.6, which explains it. I'll get the latest version and try it out. Thank you! I wasn't aware!

Comment: please check the any Scanner class is there in your folder

Answer (score 2):

Your code is absolutely fine. You need to ensure you have the latest version of JDK installed. To do that, get the latest SDK from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: I downloaded it and checked that the right version was installed, but after trying to compile it again, it still isn't working!

Comment: Check your version again

Comment: I'm positive. It said "java version 1.7.0_25".
I'm using Notepad. Do I have to save it in THAT java file bin? Right now I'm saving it in the bin from my previous download.

Answer (score 1):

You're code is great, it just has a minor error. All you needed to do was enter **Line** after the userInput.next and it should work correctly. It is corrected in the bold.

```
String result1;
    System.out.print("Please input the first word:");
    result1 = userInput.next**Line**();

    String result2;
    System.out.print("Please input the second word:");
    result2 = userInput.next**Line**();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to get this error you can skip using Scanner.

You can try

```
using java.io.Console;

public class Words{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     Console con = new System.Console();
     System.out.println("Enter some text");
     String input = con.readLine();

  }

}
```

Here is an example
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=79

and the Java documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Answer (score 0):

your code is absolutely correct. Please install the latest version of JDK and try again .